# networkx and pyviz how to add color to nodes based on dimenison

Tags: python, networkx, pyviz

I'm using `networkx` and `pyviz` together. I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the nodes in `pyviz` based an attribute in my data frame.

My dataframe looks like this:
[image]

I want to show the connections between `user_one` and `user_two` but color their nodes based on their license type.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network

df_dict = {'PROJECT': {0: 'Finance Project',  1: 'Finance Project',  2: 'Finance Project',  3: 'Finance Project',  4: 'Finance Project',  5: 'Finance Project',  6: 'Finance Project',  7: 'Finance Project',  8: 'Finance Project',  9: 'Finance Project',  10: 'Finance Project',  11: 'Finance Project',  12: 'HR Project',  13: 'Finance Project',  14: 'HR Project',  15: 'Finance Project'},
 'PLAN': {0: 'COMPANY',  1: 'COMPANY',  2: 'COMPANY',  3: 'COMPANY',  4: 'COMPANY',  5: 'COMPANY',  6: 'COMPANY',  7: 'COMPANY',  8: 'COMPANY',  9: 'COMPANY',  10: 'COMPANY',  11: 'COMPANY',  12: 'COMPANY',  13: 'COMPANY',  14: 'COMPANY',  15: 'COMPANY'},
 'USER_ONE': {0: 'Mike Jones',  1: 'Eminem',  2: 'Mike Jones',  3: 'Mike Jones',  4: 'Michael Jordan',  5: 'Eminem',  6: 'Michael Jordan',  7: 'Michael Jordan',  8: 'Mike Jones',  9: 'Kobe Bryant',  10: 'Eminem',  11: 'Elon Musk',  12: 'Bill Gates',  13: 'Elon Musk',  14: 'Mark Zuckerberg',  15: 'Elon Musk'},
 'USER_ONE_LICENSE': {0: 'FULL',  1: 'FULL',  2: 'FULL',  3: 'FULL',  4: 'FULL',  5: 'FULL',  6: 'FULL',  7: 'FULL',  8: 'FULL',  9: 'OCCASIONAL',  10: 'FULL',  11: 'FULL',  12: 'FULL',  13: 'FULL',  14: 'FULL',  15: 'FULL'},
 'USER_ONE_LICENSE_COLOR': {0: 'lightgreen',  1: 'lightgreen',  2: 'lightgreen',  3: 'lightgreen',  4: 'lightgreen',  5: 'lightgreen',  6: 'lightgreen',  7: 'lightgreen', 8: 'lightgreen',  9: 'gray',  10: 'lightgreen',  11: 'lightgreen',  12: 'lightgreen',  13: 'lightgreen',  14: 'lightgreen',  15: 'lightgreen'},
 'USER_ONE_DAYS_COLLAB': {0: 88,  1: 55,  2: 67,  3: 1,  4: 70,  5: 54,  6: 2,  7: 114,  8: 4,  9: 1,  10: 10,  11: 19,  12: 5,  13: 11,  14: 100,  15: 13},
  'USER_TWO': {0: 'Michael Jordan',  1: 'Mike Jones',  2: 'Eminem',  3: 'Kobe Bryant',  4: 'Eminem',  5: 'Michael Jordan',  6: 'Elon Musk',  7: 'Mike Jones',  8: 'Elon Musk',  9: 'Mike Jones',  10: 'Elon Musk',  11: 'Eminem',  12: 'Mark Zuckerberg',  13: 'Michael Jordan',  14: 'Bill Gates',  15: 'Mike Jones'},
 'USER_TWO_LICENSE': {0: 'FULL',  1: 'FULL',  2: 'FULL',  3: 'OCCASIONAL',  4: 'FULL',  5: 'FULL',  6: 'FULL',  7: 'FULL',  8: 'FULL',  9: 'FULL',  10: 'FULL',  11: 'FULL',  12: 'FULL',  13: 'FULL',  14: 'FULL',  15: 'FULL'},
 'USER_TWO_LICENSE_COLOR': {0: 'lightgreen',  1: 'lightgreen',  2: 'lightgreen',  3: 'gray',  4: 'lightgreen',  5: 'lightgreen',  6: 'lightgreen',  7: 'lightgreen',  8: 'lightgreen',  9: 'lightgreen',  10: 'lightgreen',  11: 'lightgreen',  12: 'lightgreen',  13: 'lightgreen',  14: 'lightgreen',  15: 'lightgreen'},
 'USER_TWO_DAYS_COLLAB': {0: 114,  1: 67,  2: 55,  3: 1,  4: 54,  5: 70,  6: 11,  7: 88,  8: 13,  9: 1,  10: 19,  11: 10,  12: 100,  13: 2,  14: 5,  15: 4}
 , 'TOTAL_COLLABS': {0: 202,  1: 122,  2: 122,  3: 2,  4: 124,  5: 124,  6: 13,  7: 202,  8: 17,  9: 2,  10: 29,  11: 29,  12: 105,  13: 13,  14: 105,  15: 17}}


df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df
                           ,source='USER_ONE'
                           ,target='USER_TWO' 
                           )

net = Network(notebook=True)

net.from_nx(G)
net.show_buttons(filter_=True)
net.show('example4.html')
```

I'm trying to follow this as a template: [Assign color to NetworkX node based on column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342586/assign-color-to-networkx-node-based-on-column-name)

```
#code from stackoverflow
colors = []
for node in G:
    if node in df["person"].values:
        colors.append("lightblue")
    else: colors.append("lightgreen")

#my attempt:
#get distinct users and respective colors based on license type
colors_df = df.groupby(by='USER_ONE')['USER_ONE_LICENSE_COLOR'].max().reset_index()

#get list of nodes in the right order
nodes_list_ordered = list(G.nodes)

#order color df so i can turn it into list to match nodes
colors_df['ORDER'] = pd.Categorical(colors_df.USER_ONE, categories = nodes_list_ordered, ordered = True)
colors_df.sort_values(by='ORDER', inplace=True)
colors = colors_df['USER_ONE_LICENSE_COLOR'].to_list()
```

Am I doing this right? I now have a list of colors in the right order, but how do I apply it to pyviz?

I did all this to realize that `from_pandas_edgelist()` does not a have `'node_color'` argument.