# If in my file there's a string that tells me the type of the node, how can I recognize it and give different colours to different nodes?

Tags: python, string, colors, nodes, networkx

I've got a file in which there are three types of nodes and I want to make a graph of them with networkx. There is a label in each line that tells me if the node is 'l', 'c' or 'n' type. The aim is to give them a different colour for every type in the graph. The real problem is that I don't know how I can recognize the string and attribute it to the node. For example in the following file (which is not the one I have to study) I want to color red the nodes with 'r' and blue the ones with 'b'

IMPORTANT : This is just an example of how the file I have to study could be, cause I can't open it, so I don't have directly knowledge of the type of each node and so on. It's an iformation I have to take from the file through the program.

```
0 1 2 r
1 5 7 b
2 8 4 r
4 9 1 r
5 3 7 b
6 0 9 b
7 8 3 r
8 1 0 r
9 7 3 r
```

The code I have written till now is:

```
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fh=open("C:/Users/secch/Downloads/Esempio.txt", 'rb')
    G=nx.read_adjlist(fh)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    for node in G:
        if node == 'r':
            nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, po s, node_color='r')
        else:
            nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color='b')      
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

Of course every node is coloured blue, cause 'if node' points to the first number of every line which defines the node.

EDIT
The file was made in this way

```
[
  directed 0
  node
  [
    id 0
    label "1000 Years for Revenge"
    value "n"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "Bush vs. the Beltway"
    value "c"
  ]
  .
  .
  .
  edge
  [
    source 1
    target 0
  ]
  edge
  [
    source 2
    target 0
  ]
```

At the end I managed in drawing the graph as I wanted. wwii's help has been the key to uderstand how to connect node's type and colours and how to recognize the lines and take the informations I needed from the file. Anyway, at the end I used for and if cycles cause I'm used to write in C++, so it was easier for me (this is my first python programme, so I hope it's not bad written).

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re,io




#defining all the different lines that can be found in the file
patternid = r'''\s+id\s+(\d+)'''
patternl = r'''\s+label\s+["]([^"]*)["]\s+'''
patternv = r'''\s+value\s+[(")]\w[(")]\s+'''
patterns = r'''\s+source\s+(\d+)'''
patternt = r'''\s+target\s+(\d+)'''
#and compiling them
patid = re.compile(patternid)
patl = re.compile(patternl)
patv = re.compile(patternv)
pats = re.compile(patterns)
patt = re.compile(patternt)
#map type to color
colors = {'"l"\n':'r','"c"\n':'b','"n"\n':'g'}

#open file and get each line in it, other ways to open file don't divide the lines in the right way
with open("C:/filepath... .txt") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()



def parse_adj(file_like_object):
    G = nx.Graph()
    #defined as globals to be used in and out of the cycles
    global node0
    global node1
    global node2
    global source
    global target
    #i to take all the 3 characteristics of the node before putting them in G and 2 informations for the edges
    #n to count all the nodes to pass to the lines of the edges
    global i
    global n
    i = 0
    n = 0
    for line in lines:
     if i < 3:
        if patid.search(line) != None: #<---to recognize the kind of line
                node0 = line.split(" ")[5] #<---To take the value we want
                i = i + 1
        if patl.search(line) != None:
                node1 = line.split(" ")[5]
                i = i + 1
        if patv.search(line) != None:
                node2 = line.split(" ")[5]
                i = i + 1
                n = n + 1
        if pats.search(line) != None:
                source = line.split(" ")[5]
                i = i + 1
                n = n + 1
        if patt.search(line) != None:
                target = line.split(" ")[5]
                i = i + 2
     else: 
        if n < 106:
           G.add_node(node0, label=node0, color=colors[node2])
           i = i - 3
        else:
           G.add_edge(source,target)
           i = i - 3
    return G

G = parse_adj(f)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colors = [thing[1] for thing in nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color').items()]
nx.draw(G, node_color=colors)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Seems like you'd be drawing the entire graph a certain color, since you're passing in `G` in your `draw_networkx_nodes` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of the lines of the file. Create a Graph with a modified copy of the [`parse_adjlist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/adjlist.html#parse_adjlist) function. The modification should extract the *color* information from each line and use it for a node (or edge) attribute.

```
with open("C:/Users/secch/Downloads/Esempio.txt") as f:
    lines = list(f)
G = parse_myadjlist(lines)
```

Use the node attribute to determine the color. (subsituted `nx.spring_layout(G)` for `pos` in your example because you didn't specify it.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colors = [thing[1] for thing in nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color').items()]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=colors)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]]

---

Modified function to parse given example:

```
def parse_myadjlist(lines, comments='#', delimiter=None,
                  create_using=None, nodetype=None):
    """Parse lines of a graph adjacency list representation.

    Custom adjacency format.
    Some words here describing the modification

    Returns
    -------
    G: NetworkX graph
        The graph corresponding to the lines in adjacency list format.

    Examples
    --------
    Maybe an example or two here

    """
    G = nx.empty_graph(0, create_using)
    for line in lines:
        p = line.find(comments)
        if p >= 0:
            line = line[:p]
        if not len(line):
            continue
        vlist = line.strip().split(delimiter)
        u = vlist.pop(0)
        color = vlist.pop(-1)    # <--- for your example, the color info is the last character
        attrs = {'color':color}  # <--- make an attribute dictionary
        # convert types
        if nodetype is not None:
            try:
                u = nodetype(u)
            except:
                raise TypeError("Failed to convert node ({}) to type {}"
                                .format(u, nodetype))
        G.add_node(u,**attrs)    # <--- add node with attribute
        if nodetype is not None:
            try:
                vlist = map(nodetype, vlist)
            except:
                raise TypeError("Failed to convert nodes ({}) to type {}"
                                .format(','.join(vlist), nodetype))
        G.add_edges_from([(u, v) for v in vlist],**attrs)    # <--- add edges with attribute
    return G
```

---

If the file looks like this:

```
node [ id 0 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 1 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
node [ id 0 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 3 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ]  node [ id 7 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ]
node [ id 1 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 2 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
node [ id 3 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 4 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ] node [ id 6 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
```

The process is similar - the node information extraction needs to be tailored to the data.  Regular expressions look like a good fit .

```
import re,io
import networkx as nx

pattern1 = r'''node.*?id\s+(\d+)\s+label\s+["]([^"]*)["]\s+value\s+["]([^"]*)["]\s[]]'''
parse = re.compile(pattern1)

#map type to color
colors = {'l':'r','c':'g','n':'b'}

def parse_adj(file_like_object):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for line in file_like_object:
        # extract node info from line
        node1, *othernodes = [node for node in parse.findall(line.strip())]
        G.add_node(node1[0], label=node1[1], color=colors[node1[2]])
        for node in othernodes:
            G.add_node(node[0], label=node[1], color=colors[node[2]])
            G.add_edge(node1[0],node[0])
    return G

s = '''node [ id 0 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 1 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
node [ id 0 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 3 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ]  node [ id 7 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ]
node [ id 1 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 2 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
node [ id 3 label "1000 Years for Revenge" value "n" ] node [ id 4 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "l" ] node [ id 6 label "Bush vs. the Beltway" value "c" ]
'''

def parse_adj(file_like_object):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for line in file_like_object:
        # extract node info from line
        node1, *othernodes = [node for node in parse.findall(line.strip())]
        # add the node
        G.add_node(node1[0], label=node1[1], color=colors[node1[2]])
        # add other nodes and edges
        for node in othernodes:
            G.add_node(node[0], label=node[1], color=colors[node[2]])
            G.add_edge(node1[0],node[0])
    return G

G = parse_adj(f)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
colors = [thing[1] for thing in nx.get_node_attributes(G,'color').items()]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=colors)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to put in the argument of "lines=list(?)" because a thing I didn't specified is that I can't open the file I have to study. So I don't know which nodes are of the 'l', 'c' or 'n' type. I just know that there is this kind of specification. The file I posted is just an example of how it could be.

Comment: `The file I posted is just an example of how it could be` - This solution is for the specific format in your example. If you do not know in advance the structure of the lines in the file I don't see how you can parse the lines/nodes to know what color it should be.

Comment: First of all, thak you very much for your time and examples. You answered to my question: there's no way if I don't know the aspect of my file.

Then, I managed in changing my file format into .txt .

Comment: First of all, thak you very much for your time and examples. You answered to my question: there's no way if I don't know the aspect of my file.

Then, I managed in changing my file format into .txt . I have seen that it is different from how I imagined it.
That's the way it's made

node
  [
    id 0
    label "1000 Years for Revenge"
    value "n"
  ]
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "Bush vs. the Beltway"
    value "c"
  ]

.
.
.
ecc...

Probably it's easier than before, but anyway I don't know how to make blue (for example) the 'c' value nodes.

Comment: Probably I have to make another question now, cause in a comment it's not enough clear.

Comment: The process would be the same. You just need to tailor it to the format of your data. The code that extracts the information from each line should be the only thing that would be different from my solution. - you should concentrate on that, just take a couple of lines and try to *parse* them.  You should try it yourself then post a new question if you run into problems parsing the lines.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, using the code you wrote with the file I posted as example, only three nodes appeared (all red).

Comment: It tells me that the problem is in line 
    node1, *othernodes = [....]
Tells me "not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1)"

I don't understand how this line works.

Comment: Well, you did not provide an example of the actual file so I extrapolated from your comment and made something up. The point is that you have to figure out how to extract the relevant information from the text and you need to know how the text is structured to figure it out. You should concentrate on that aspect and try to formulate a process for your specific file. Then ask a new question if you run into problems. Be sure to include anything relevant. Read [mcve]. We should be able to copy and paste from your question.

Comment: Your initial question seemed to me to be `how do I give each node a color`? and I thought it was a Networkx question because you provided a *made-up* file that did not represent the actual data you are using. But it turns out that you are actually asking `How do I parse this file to extract x,y, and z` . If possible, feel free to un-accept this answer or I can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to exactly specify the color assigned to each node, that has been discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030473/how-to-set-colors-for-nodes-in-networkx-python).  However, if you want something a little more dynamic...

A good description of how to do this can be found on [this site](https://python-graph-gallery.com/324-map-a-color-to-network-nodes/).  The general idea on that site is that you want to give a categorical index to the graph.  However, you have to be aware of the node order in `networkx` and that it might not be what you expect.  So that link will walk you through a way to deal with that.

I have a bit of an easier way that I have made it work in the past.  This example is for two categories, but you could easily expand it to more.

```
G = nx.Graph()

node_ls = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5', 'u6', 'u7', 'r1', 'r2']

# Here I represent the edges as a list of tuples where the final value in the tuple
# is the category.  Like the above link, you might want to convert your text
# category into a number since the color mapping will go easier.

edge_ls = [('u1', 'r1', 0), ('u1', 'r2', 0), ('u1', 'r3', 0), 
           ('u2', 'r3', 1), ('u2', 'r6', 1), ('u2', 'r7', 1), 
           ('u3', 'r3', 0), ('u3', 'r4', 0), ('u3', 'r5', 0), 
           ('u3', 'r6', 0)]

cat = []
for element in edge_ls:
    G.add_edge(element[0], element[1])
    cat.append(element[2])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color=cat, cmap=plt.cm.Set1, node_size=1500)
```

Comment: The file I posted is just an example. In the other one I don't know which nodes are 'l', 'n' or 'c', cause i can't open it. I don't even know in which line the types are specified. So no, i don't believe the answer is in that question you posted, I saw it before posting this question and it didn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you give an example of the file in question?  Should we address not being able to open it instead of the node color problem first?

Comment: You're right. I managed in changing the layout. Now i'll probably have to open another question. Thank you very much for your time.