# Draw shapes on top of Networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

Given an existing `networkx` graph

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(5, 0.3, seed=123, directed=True)
nx.draw_networkx(graph)
```

[image]

or

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(4)
nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

[image]

how can you draw a red circle on top of (in the same position as) one of the nodes, like the node labeled `1`?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220877/highlight-a-node-in-draw-networkx-visualisation-without-changing-node-colour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to draw a networkx graph, each node needs to be assigned a position. By default, `nx.spring_layout()` is used to calculate positions when calling `nx.draw_networkx()`, but these positions aren't stored. They are recalculated each time the function is drawn, except when the positions are explicitly added as a parameter.

Therefore, you can calculate these positions beforehand, and then use these to plot circles:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(5, 0.3, seed=123, directed=True)
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos=pos)
ax = plt.gca()
for node_id, color in zip([1, 4], ['crimson', 'limegreen']):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(pos[node_id], 0.15, facecolor=to_rgba(color, alpha=0.2), edgecolor=color))
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')  # equal aspect ratio is needed to show circles undistorted
plt.show()
```

[image: networkx graph drawing with added circles]