# Networkx: nodes in the network disappear when colouring

Tags: pandas, networkx

I have a network graph in networkx created from a dictionary and want to colour a subset of nodes in a specific colour.

I created the original network graph using
`nx.draw_networkx(g, with_labels=False, node_size=20)`

Then I tried to colour a specific node in a different colour using the suggested solution in [How to set colors for nodes in NetworkX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030473/how-to-set-colors-for-nodes-in-networkx)

Problems:

1. The code colours the node, but at the same time makes a lot of the other nodes disappear. What am I doing wrong?
2. Once 1) is resolved, what is the best way to modify the code to colour  several nodes?

Thank you for your help!

```
for node in g:
    if node == 'Bob':
        color_map.append('red')
    else:
        color_map.append('blue')
            
nx.draw(g, node_color=color_map, with_labels=False, node_size=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example where you can color code multiple nodes with a mapping dictionary. I was not able to reproduce the issue of missing nodes, run this code with your data and see if any nodes are missing.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([('Bob', 'Steve'), ('Bob', 'Jeff'), ('Jeff', 'George'), ('Jeff', 'Steve')])

node_map = {'Bob': 'red', 'Jeff': 'green'}
color_map = [node_map.get(n, 'blue') for n in g.nodes]

nx.draw_networkx(g, node_color=color_map, with_labels=True, node_size=200)
plt.show()
```

[image: networkx graph]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I just got back to this task! Your code is working and there are no nodes disappearing now. I think there was a problem with my initial code. Sorry that I couldn't provide an example, but I actually have 423 nodes and the problem seemed to be with the data/my code. Will try to provide a toy example for any further questions though.