# networkx referring to multi-dimensions and displaying data

Tags: python, networkx

new to network graphs so was hoping for a little guidance...

I'm trying to create a network graph between users collaborating with each other, my problem is I cannot figure out how to add multiple dimensions to the network.

At a high level I want to show:

1. User-to-User interactions
2. Add some sort of size indication of users who are collaborating more (via the edges, the more interactions the thicker the line between the two users).
3. Add color to the edges/lines indicating the project they worked on together
4. Add color to node based on user license type

So something like:

[image]

So far I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network

df_dict = {'PROJECT': {0: 'Finance Project',  1: 'Finance Project',  2: 'Finance Project',  3: 'Finance Project',  4: 'Finance Project',  5: 'Finance Project',  6: 'Finance Project',  7: 'Finance Project',  8: 'Finance Project',  9: 'Finance Project',  10: 'Finance Project',  11: 'Finance Project',  12: 'HR Project',  13: 'Finance Project',  14: 'HR Project',  15: 'Finance Project'},
 'PLAN': {0: 'COMPANY',  1: 'COMPANY',  2: 'COMPANY',  3: 'COMPANY',  4: 'COMPANY',  5: 'COMPANY',  6: 'COMPANY',  7: 'COMPANY',  8: 'COMPANY',  9: 'COMPANY',  10: 'COMPANY',  11: 'COMPANY',  12: 'COMPANY',  13: 'COMPANY',  14: 'COMPANY',  15: 'COMPANY'},
 'USER_ONE': {0: 'Mike Jones',  1: 'Eminem',  2: 'Mike Jones',  3: 'Mike Jones',  4: 'Michael Jordan',  5: 'Eminem',  6: 'Michael Jordan',  7: 'Michael Jordan',  8: 'Mike Jones',  9: 'Kobe Bryant',  10: 'Eminem',  11: 'Elon Musk',  12: 'Bill Gates',  13: 'Elon Musk',  14: 'Mark Zuckerberg',  15: 'Elon Musk'},
 'USER_ONE_LICENSE': {0: 'FULL',  1: 'FULL',  2: 'FULL',  3: 'FULL',  4: 'FULL',  5: 'FULL',  6: 'FULL',  7: 'FULL',  8: 'FULL',  9: 'OCCASIONAL',  10: 'FULL',  11: 'FULL',  12: 'FULL',  13: 'FULL',  14: 'FULL',  15: 'FULL'},
 'USER_ONE_LICENSE_COLOR': {0: 'lightgreen',  1: 'lightgreen',  2: 'lightgreen',  3: 'lightgreen',  4: 'lightgreen',  5: 'lightgreen',  6: 'lightgreen',  7: 'lightgreen', 8: 'lightgreen',  9: 'gray',  10: 'lightgreen',  11: 'lightgreen',  12: 'lightgreen',  13: 'lightgreen',  14: 'lightgreen',  15: 'lightgreen'},
 'USER_ONE_DAYS_COLLAB': {0: 88,  1: 55,  2: 67,  3: 1,  4: 70,  5: 54,  6: 2,  7: 114,  8: 4,  9: 1,  10: 10,  11: 19,  12: 5,  13: 11,  14: 100,  15: 13},
  'USER_TWO': {0: 'Michael Jordan',  1: 'Mike Jones',  2: 'Eminem',  3: 'Kobe Bryant',  4: 'Eminem',  5: 'Michael Jordan',  6: 'Elon Musk',  7: 'Mike Jones',  8: 'Elon Musk',  9: 'Mike Jones',  10: 'Elon Musk',  11: 'Eminem',  12: 'Mark Zuckerberg',  13: 'Michael Jordan',  14: 'Bill Gates',  15: 'Mike Jones'},
 'USER_TWO_LICENSE': {0: 'FULL',  1: 'FULL',  2: 'FULL',  3: 'OCCASIONAL',  4: 'FULL',  5: 'FULL',  6: 'FULL',  7: 'FULL',  8: 'FULL',  9: 'FULL',  10: 'FULL',  11: 'FULL',  12: 'FULL',  13: 'FULL',  14: 'FULL',  15: 'FULL'},
 'USER_TWO_LICENSE_COLOR': {0: 'lightgreen',  1: 'lightgreen',  2: 'lightgreen',  3: 'gray',  4: 'lightgreen',  5: 'lightgreen',  6: 'lightgreen',  7: 'lightgreen',  8: 'lightgreen',  9: 'lightgreen',  10: 'lightgreen',  11: 'lightgreen',  12: 'lightgreen',  13: 'lightgreen',  14: 'lightgreen',  15: 'lightgreen'},
 'USER_TWO_DAYS_COLLAB': {0: 114,  1: 67,  2: 55,  3: 1,  4: 54,  5: 70,  6: 11,  7: 88,  8: 13,  9: 1,  10: 19,  11: 10,  12: 100,  13: 2,  14: 5,  15: 4}
 , 'TOTAL_COLLABS': {0: 202,  1: 122,  2: 122,  3: 2,  4: 124,  5: 124,  6: 13,  7: 202,  8: 17,  9: 2,  10: 29,  11: 29,  12: 105,  13: 13,  14: 105,  15: 17}}


df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)



# where do I add all the other attributes?
#i.e. license type, project, # of interactions (I'm assuming this can be something like weights?) 
#In my case I believe my source + target needs to be Project + User? 
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df
                           ,source='USER_ONE'
                           ,target='USER_TWO' #I tried ['PROJECT','USER_TWO']
                           )

net = Network(notebook=True)

net.from_nx(G)
net.show_buttons(filter_=True)
net.show('example4.html')
```

1. All the examples I've seen only have one source and one target - mine needs user + project for both source and target. Is there a way to do this without creating one field that combines both?
2. Haven't found a clear way to [color nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030473/how-to-set-colors-for-nodes-in-networkx) , the example provided shows a case on the node value (in my case the node is just text, i have another dimension i want to refer to to dictate color)

Haven't found a clear way to build a case statement on [edge width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-result) either. Concretely:

- if count of interactions  <= 1 then "small width"
- if count of interactions  > 1 and <=5 then "medium width"
  etc...

Any direction or resources would be greatly appreciated -- everything I come across seems to be different than my setup leaving me unsure how to proceed.

my table looks something like this for reference:

[image]

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: it would be much simpler if you would add example data as text - or even better as code `pd.DataFrame(...)`

Comment: it may need something more than only `from_pandas_edgelist`. It may need to add colors and other elements separately